# Why does WTSFreeMemoryExA always return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when passed a WTSTypeClass of WTSTypeSessionInfoLevel1?

Tags: winapi, remote-desktop, wtsapi32

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsfreememoryexa), `WTSFreeMemoryExA` can be used to free a [`WTS_SESSION_INFO_1A`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wts_session_info_1a) structure by passing a [`WTS_TYPE_CLASS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-wts_type_class) of `WTSTypeSessionInfoLevel1`. However, any attempt to do so fails with error code 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, `"The parameter is incorrect"`).

How to get `WTSFreeMemoryExA` to work?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Windows (at least in Windows 10 version 2004). Contrary to the documentation, the `WTSFreeMemoryExA` function does not accept `WTSTypeSessionInfoLevel1`, whereas `WTSFreeMemoryExW` does. This means that instead of using the [`WTSEnumerateSessionsExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsexa) function which returns [`WTS_SESSION_INFO_1A`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wts_session_info_1a)  structures, you need to instead use the [`WTSEnumerateSessionsExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsexw) function which returns [`WTS_SESSION_INFO_1W`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wts_session_info_1w).

This bug effectively makes `WTSEnumerateSessionsExA` unusable, unless you don't care about the memory leak caused by the inability to free its results. This bug [appears](http://redplait.blogspot.com/2018/08/bug-in-wtsapi32wtsfreememoryexa.html) to have been known about for some time. (Hopefully, some day, Microsoft will fix this.)

[Some reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839270/memory-leak-issues-with-windows-api-call-delphi) claim that even using `WTSEnumerateSessionsExW` and `WTSFreeMemoryExW` appears to leak memory, which implies that `WTSEnumerateSessions` combined with `WTSQuerySessionInformation` may be [the better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17854383). However, I myself have been unable to reproduce that issue. I suspect it was a real issue at one point, but has been fixed by Microsoft in more recent Windows versions.

Comment: Hi,I can reproduce this issue now. And I will confirm it with Internal engineer, and response here if there is any update. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It's probably a bug in user code to be using WTS_SESSION_INFO_1A anyway because, well, you don't need me to explain why the Unicode API is preferred. So it's not exactly a high priority to fix this defect.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Historically what you say is correct, but with the introduction of [UTF-8 support in Win10 version 1903](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) the W-over-A preference arguably no longer applies, so this bug would be higher priority than it used to be. And a UTF-8 code page app using A apis instead of W is not a bug. With UTF-8 code page, now A apis are Unicode too. (W=UTF-16, A=UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

thank you for raising this question.

We checked the relevant source code and found the source code related to `WTSFreeMemoryA`. It accepts the first parameter `WTSTypeClass` as `WTSTypeProcessInfoLevel0` or `WTSTypeProcessInfoLevel1`, but it doesn’t accept the value `WTSTypeSessionInfoLevel1` and therefore return the `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error on this call.

This is different from the description in the document, we will submit this issue. And you can try to use `WTSFreeMemoryW` to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When you say `WTSFreeMemoryA`, you mean `WTSFreeMemoryExA`, right? (Likewise for `WTSFreeMemoryW`.) Also, I understand you are a Microsoft employee? It might be good to clarify that in your answer. (Otherwise people will be wondering how you are checking the Windows source code.)